# I want to change my rich text editor value into complete Html format at android?

Tags: android, html, rich-text-editor

I used [this](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android) library for Rich text editor for my project.

When I get `mEditor.getHtml()`, it gives normal string, but I want `mEditor` value into `html` format fully with `css` what I applied . I used `Html.toHtml(spannedText)`, but it is not working completely, it shows just paragraph tag only, I need complete `html` code with `css`. I really new to this concept, if anybody knows can you please give me for solve this problem.

Comment: try using **getText()** method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String styledText = Html.toHtml(mEditor.getText());
```

Comment: I tried thsi, but it does not support all thml tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mEditor.setOnTextChangeListener(new RichEditor.OnTextChangeListener() {
  @Override public void onTextChange(String text) {
  String formattedText = getString(R.string.htmlFormattedText);
  Spanned result = Html.fromHtml(formattedText);
    view.setText(text);


  }
});
```